# How can I improve this script to delete a left over table?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

This script basically makes it so that it deletes content from specific users from a forum. It is working as intended but there is still a left over element (table) from the deleted content. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Code:
https://greasyfork.org/scripts/2690-fitmisc-total-ignore/code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Fitmisc_Total_Ignore
// @author Arris
// @description This script is designed to completly eradicate from sight the worst posters on Fitmisc.com
// @include http://fitmisc.com/*
// @namespace http://fitmisc.com/
// @version 0.9
// ==/UserScript==

function canIgnore(sUser) {
    if( sUser.match(/niko/i) )
        return true;
    if( sUser.match(/thesavagepony/i) )
        return true;
    if( sUser.match(/Lloyd Banks/i) )
        return true;
    if( sUser.match(/Lil B/i) )
        return true;
    if( sUser.match(/Round-Mound/i) )
        return true;
    return false; 
}

function setIgnoreThread() {
    var a; var s;

    a=document.evaluate(
    "//div[starts-with(@class, 'threadmeta')]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
    for (var i=0; i<a.snapshotLength; i++) {
        s=a.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML;
        if( canIgnore(s) ) {
            //a.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            a.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
}

function setIgnorePost() {
    var a; var s;

    a=document.evaluate(
    "//div[starts-with(@class, 'username_container')]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
    for (var i=0; i<a.snapshotLength; i++) {
        s=a.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML;
        if( canIgnore(s) ) {
            //a.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            a.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = '<li class="postbitlegacy postbitim postcontainer old" style="background:white;border-color:white;"></li>';
        }
    }
}

function setIgnoreQuote() {
    var a; var s;

    a=document.evaluate(
    "//div[starts-with(@class, 'bbcode_postedby')]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
    for (var i=0; i<a.snapshotLength; i++) {
        s=a.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML;
        if( canIgnore(s) ) {
            //a.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            a.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
}

if(window.opera) { //opera only
    (function(){
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            setIgnoreThread();
            setIgnorePost();
            setIgnoreQuote();
        }, false);
    })()
} else {
    setIgnoreThread();
    setIgnorePost();
    setIgnoreQuote();
}
```

Comment: please put the code here

Comment: I tried to, but it adds it by chunks with the wrong format. Maybe i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Put it and I'll fix it

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you

Comment: @Arris Why do you use regular expressions if you don't need its power? To check if string contains substring you can use `indexOf`, it will be (probably) faster.

Comment: Can you add a sample of code of the forum?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hardcode the usernames each in a dedicated regulare expression consider a generation of a single expression matching any item of an array of ignored user names. Use the RegExp.test() method when you don't need to store a result.

*(I've removed user names in my examples, except the anonymous operator account "OP". I don't like defamation in the public.)*

```
var
  ignoredUsers = ['user 1', 'another user', 'OP', 'yet another user']
;

function canIgnore(sUser)
{
  return new RegExp(ignoredUsers.join('|'), 'i').test(sUser);
}
```

However, there's no need to extract user names, check them against regular expressions and do further processing, since you are using XPath expressions which can find content and step back in the DOM tree. They are capable to retrieve all text nodes with one of a list of users inside a container class and give back their ancestors ([grand]parents) selected by a class.

```
// = =UserScript= =
// @name Fitmisc_Total_Ignore
// @author Arris
// @description This script is designed to completly eradicate from sight the worst posters on Fitmisc.com
// @include http://fitmisc.com/*
// @namespace http://fitmisc.com/
// @grant          GM_xpath
// @version 0.9
// = =/UserScript= =

var
  // TODO: GM_ get/set Value as JSON ; put users into igno list by mouse click
  ignoredUsers = ['user 1', 'another user', 'OP', 'yet another user']
;

function removeContents(ignoreList)
{
  if(ignoreList instanceof Array && ignoreList.length)
    GM_xpath
    ( { path: "//div[@class='username_container']//*[text() = '"
            + ignoreList.map(function(user) { return user.replace("'", "\\'"); } ).join("' or text() = '")
            + "']/ancestor::li[contains(@class, 'postcontainer')]",
        all :true 
      }
    ).forEach(function(elem){ elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem); });
}

removeContents(ignoredUsers);
```

Since users accounts could be renamed, consider to filter user id, e.g. in the `href` attribute of profile link or photo, instead of relying on changable names.

The expample above does the job on thread posts. You can combine multiple XPath expressions into one by the "|" char.